# Interstitial Ads kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have implemented the interstitial ads (admob) in my app, but the ads are showing after any click and right after i open my app without doing anything.

How can show interstitial ads after x clicks and how can i hide the ad that appear when i open the app?

sample of the app: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x5vf6VY3mHu0S-aNnKeLQaq3FF-_9Xjx/view?usp=sharing

part of mainactivity.kt:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    hasCollections = boolean(R.bool.show_collections_tab)
    val correct = if (hasCollections) 1 else 0
    lastSection = savedInstanceState?.getInt("current", correct) ?: correct

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")
    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())

    mInterstitialAd.adListener = object: AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded() {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
                mInterstitialAd.show()
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.")
            }
        }
    }

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    initPagerAdapter()

    tabs?.setTabTextColors(
        getDisabledTextColorFor(primaryColor),
        if (boolean(R.bool.accent_in_tabs)) accentColor
        else getPrimaryTextColorFor(primaryColor))
    tabs?.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(
        if (boolean(R.bool.accent_in_tabs)) accentColor
        else getPrimaryTextColorFor(primaryColor))
    if (boolean(R.bool.show_icons_in_tabs)) {
        tabs?.setTabsIconsColors(
            getInactiveIconsColorFor(primaryColor),
            if (boolean(R.bool.accent_in_tabs)) accentColor
            else getActiveIconsColorFor(primaryColor))
    }

    buildTabs()

    tabs?.addOnTabSelectedListener(
        object : TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(pager) {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                tab?.let { postDelayed(50) { navigateToSection(it.position) } }
            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) = scrollToTop()
            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
        })
    pager?.addOnPageChangeListener(
        TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs))

    pager?.offscreenPageLimit = tabs?.tabCount ?: 2

    navigateToSection(lastSection, true)

    favsViewModel.observe(this) { notifyFavsToFrags(it) }
    doAsync { favsViewModel.loadData(favsDB.favoritesDao(), true) }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You start loading the ad in your `onCreate()` method, which is called right after the launch of your `MainActivity`. Therefore, your callback method `onAdLoaded()` will display the ad as soon as it is loaded.

If you want to display the ad later you have two options :

1. wait to load the ad, by calling `loadAd()` later,
2. load your ad at the start of your activity, but call the `mInterstitialAd.show()` method later. This way, your ad will be loaded, but won't be displayed until you want it.